# Equation solving to find a matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

If I have the vector `z={y1+2*y2+y3,y1+y2,y1+y2+y3}` , and `y={y1,y2,y3}` and `m=Array[a,{3,3}]`. How to solve `m.y=z` to get that `m={{1,2,1},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}}`

Comment: You give `z` as both a vector and an array. They don't equate to each other.

Comment: `m = D[z, {y}]` gives `{{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}` and satisfies `m . y == z`.

Comment: I edited it and thank your answer helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean this

```
m = {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
aa = Array[a, {3, 3}]
y = {y1, y2, y3}
z = {y1 + 2*y2 + y3, y1 + y2, y1 + y2 + y3}

sa = First@SolveAlways[Thread[aa.y == z], y]

aa /. sa // MatrixForm

m == aa /. sa

(*   True   *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
z = {y1 + 2*y2 + y3, y1 + y2, y1 + y2 + y3};
y = {y1, y2, y3};
m = Array[a, {3, 3}];
eq = ForAll[y // Evaluate, m . y == z];
sol = Resolve[eq]
Simplify[m, sol]
```

> `{{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}`